# Anti-holomorphic involution induced by complex conjugation

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface. What is the antiholomorphic involution $\sigma: X\to X$ induced by the complex conjugation?

I don't understand how can we define $\sigma$. For example take $x\in X$ send it with a local chart $\phi_U$, to $\phi_U(x)\in\mathbb C$, the apply the conjugation $\overline {\phi_U(x)}\in\mathbb C$. How do we come back to $X$ in order to define $\sigma(x)?$

Comment: In what context did you encounter this map?  You are right that it does not make since if $X$ is just an arbitrary Riemann surface.

Comment: For example page 5 of this book: https://books.google.it/books?id=Aw01bnsKCrcC&pg=PA1&hl=fr&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

Last paragraph before section 3. It mentions the complex conjugation of a Riemann surface.

Comment: Sometimes an hermitian vector bundle is required to be "invariant under conjugation". But I have no idea of the meaning of this sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be a two dimensional real manifold, if it exists a Riemann surface structure $X$ on $Y$ is given by some charts $\phi_j : U_j\subset \Bbb{C}\to Y$, such that $f : X\to \Bbb{C}$ is meromorphic iff $\forall j, f\circ \phi_j$ is meromorphic on its domain, and the chart compatibility condition is that $Y$ is covered by $\bigcup_j \phi_j(U_j)$ and each $\phi_j^{-1}\phi_i$ is analytic on its domain.

There is another Riemann surface structure $X^*$ obtained from the charts $$\phi_j^* : \overline{U_j}\to Y,\qquad \phi_j^*(z)=\phi_j(\overline{z})$$ It satisfies the chart compatibility condition and the identity on the underlying real manifold is an anti-holomorphic bijection $X\to X^*$, and $p\mapsto f(p)$ is meromorphic $X\to \Bbb{C}$ iff $p\mapsto \overline{f(p)}$ is meromorphic $X^*\to \Bbb{C}$.

When $X$ is connected compact its field of meromorphic functions is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}(x)[y]/(q(x,y))$ with $q(x,y)=\sum_{n,m} a_{n,m}x^n y^m\in \Bbb{C}(x)[y]$ monic irreducible and the function field of $X^*$ is $\Bbb{C}(z)[w]/(q^*(z,w))$ where $q^*(z,w)=\sum_{n,m} \overline{a_{n,m}}z^n w^m$. The anti-holomoprhic map above is $(x,y) \to (z,w), c\in\Bbb{C}\to \overline{c}$.

The uniformization theorem (embedding the universal cover into $\Bbb{C}\cup \infty$) is another way to visualize $X^*$.

Comment: So basically you are saying that the involution is well defined even if the Riemann surface is not a projective curve with coefficients in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: It is well-defined for all complex manifold, the point is that it is the identity on the underlying real manifold, but (in general) it sends the complex manifold to another one, and on the functions side it is just taking the complex conjugate (thus it is not $\Bbb{C}$-linear only anti-linear)

Comment: To have a canonical way of identifying $X^*$ with $X$ (as a complex manifold), though, you need $X$ to be something like a variety defined over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey With $F$ the function field of a complex variety, for $\sigma$ a $\Bbb{C}$-antilinear isomorphism $F\to F$, the fixed subfield $F^\sigma$ is defined over $\Bbb{R}$ and $[F:F^\sigma]=2\implies F=F^\sigma(i)$ thus the variety is defined over $\Bbb{R}$. The two fields $F^\sigma=\Bbb{R}(x)[y]/(y^2-x^3-1),F^{\sigma'}=\Bbb{R}(X)[Y]/(Y^2-X^3+1)$ of two non-isomorphic real elliptic curves that become isomorphic over $\Bbb{C}$ show that $\sigma$ doesn't need to be unique. There is a $\Bbb{C}$-isomorphism $\sigma(F)\to \sigma'(F)$: the isomorphism class of the image by $\sigma$ is unique

Answer (score 1):

This only makes sense when $X$ has additional structure.  In particular, if $X$ is a curve in $\mathbb{P}^n$ which is defined by a collection of polynomials with real coefficients, then the map $\mathbb{P}^n\to\mathbb{P}^n$ given by complex conjugation on each homogeneous coordinate restricts to an anti-holomorphic involution of $X$.

Comment: Yes it is clear. We need some algebraic structure.

Comment: anything unclear in my answer, the anti-holomorphic involution is the identity $Y\to Y$ which sends $X\to X^*$, the difference being between the Riemann surface and the underlying real manifold, it doesn't depend on a choice of chart so it is always defined @manifold